# Going back to angular page after successful login?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, authentication, cas

So I'm developing an Angular app that has user authentication.

I'm not responsible for the backend side of the authentication.

The project as it is currently has an endpoint that I hit to hit the login page that's hosted separately.

So here's how it goes.

(These are sample names)

Our main webapp has a link like https://node11.dev.com/webappname

The user login for this webapp goes

https://node11.dev.com:8082/api/applications/webappname/user/login/

And when you hit that endpoint you get

https://node3.dev.com/cas/login?service = A link to the endpoint it got redirected from along with a JSessionId

Pretty sure we're using Spring + CAS Web Security.

I login fine with my username and password, however after a successful login, I just return to a blank page with the url

https://node11.dev.com:8082/api/applications/user/login.

I need to redirect back to the main app page, along with enabling logouts and what not.

How do I go about this?

Some code that is relevant.

This is in the navigation HTML where this login button is on the UI.

```
<a class="user" href="https://node17.catapult.dev.boozallenet.com:8082/api/applications/godzilla/login"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Login <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
```

Previously instead of href I had an ng-click because I felt I would probably have to use a POST or a GET.

When I was using ng-click, it called a function goToLogin, and this is what that function did.

```
function goToLogin(){
       $window.location.href=url;

    }
```

Comment: Can you post any relevant code? Otherwise it's hard to identify the issue.

Comment: way too many unknowns here but if you are using `ui-router` a resolve in main parent route might help you

Answer (score 0):

Are you GETing or POSTing? You should probably POST to that url with ajax and let angular verify that the login was successful (via the server response). Then you can use whatever router (ui-router is a popular if frustrating solution) to invoke the logged-in state from angular.

Comment: Currently. Neither. On the UI end it's accomplished via an anchor tag with the href set to this: https://node11.dev.com:8082/api/applications/user/login

If I was to POST, how I would I accomplish what you stated.

Comment: I'd use the $http service bundled with angular. On login form submit (ng-submit) execute a function that uses $http (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to POST the credentials to your server endpoint. Then in your success function get and save a session token (jsessionid) that you can use as a parameter on subsequent requests to the server. Having that token means you're logged in. UI-Router (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) is a whole other can of beans but that's how I navigate to a new page within angular.

Comment: I don't have a separate form for the login unfortunately. The login that shows is not a part of this app, but is a separate front end piece for that CAS web service. I guess the simplest way would be to make a Login template for HTML and on form submit as you suggest hit that endpoint.

Comment: Yeah, any sort of thing inside of Angular would work. If you must use the separate front-end piece you can use localStorage or cookies and just look for that data once you're redirected back to angular (the other component will have to set your window location back to angular on success). I've had to do something similar in Angular for an app that doesn't have it's own auth and lives inside an iframe in another app. We just listen for a postMessage containing an auth token from the server and use that with subsequent requests.

Comment: How would I approach it with cookies?

Comment: just use document.cookie (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp). Personally I'm partial to window.localStorage or window.sessionStorage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Answer (score 0):

The best case to solve this is use switch case in the APP, initially make the value of switch to false, after  successfully login or responce from the server make the value of switch to true.

```
<div ng-switch on="loginData" >   <!-- begin switch -->

    <div ng-switch-when="false" ng-controller="loginController" ng-init="initLogin()">  
</div>

 <div ng-switch-when="true" ng-controller="dataController"> 
</div>
</div>
```

another solution

use routing in ur app
use just ng-binding div

```
var module = angular.module("SalesApp", ['ngRoute']);
module.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider','$httpProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {
           // var dir = window.location.pathname;
            $routeProvider.
                when('/dashboard', {
                    templateUrl: 'frontView.html',
                }).
                when('/searchresult', {
                    templateUrl: 'resultContainer.html',
                }).
                when('/postad', {
                    templateUrl: 'postAd.html',
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/dashboard'
                });
        }]);
```

and after login just change the root of the div.

```
$location.path(pagePath);
```

Both Works for me to a great extent 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This did eventually end up getting resolved. Based on the design our app, I couldn't fix it from the front end. On the back end, they had to change the CAS redirect url back to the original app url.